# How to copy a column to an array by offset?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

How to store all non empty cells from a column in Excel as a one-dimensional array starting from an offset?

**Example**:

I want to store all cells as individual items in a one-dimensional array
from `Column B` starting from offset `Row 3`. If a cell is empty I do not want to store it.

```
myArr = Range("B3:" & last_non_empty_cell_in_B).Value
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more information.

Comment: Also please do not use Deprecated tags. Before using a tag, understand what that tag is all about :)

Comment: Thank you! Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `Autofilter` on column B then copy the visible cells to the array

```
Sub columnB()
  Dim B As Range, cel As Range, i As Long, myArr
  With Sheet1
    Set B = .Range("B3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    B.AutoFilter 1, "<>" ' <-- autofilter out blank cells
    ReDim myArr(B.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1) ' <-- size the array accordingly
    For Each cel In B.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' <-- copy cells individually to array
      myArr(i) = cel.Value2
      i = i + 1
    Next
    .Cells.AutoFilter ' now remove the autofilter
  End With

  ' now you have you array myArr
End Sub
```

To make it a function that returns an array of strings:

```
Function GetNonEmptyFromColumn(col As String, headerRow As String) As String()
  Dim B As Range, cel As Range, i As Long, myArr() As String
  With Sheet1
    Set B = .Range(col & headerRow, .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp))
    B.AutoFilter 1, "<>" ' <-- autofilter out blank cells
    ReDim myArr(B.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1) As String ' <-- size the array accordingly
    For Each cel In B.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' <-- copy cells individually to array
      myArr(i) = cel.Value2
      i = i + 1
    Next
    .Cells.AutoFilter ' now remove the autofilter
  End With

  GetNonEmptyFromColumn = myArr
  ' now you have you array myArr
End Function


Sub Test()
  Dim s() As String
  s = GetNonEmptyFromColumn("B", 4)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice on the 20K :)

Comment: @ShaiRado, I know who's next ;). Welcome back btw!

Comment: @A.S.H Your code works wonders thank you! This is not really part of the question but why doesn't this work? `Dim arr() As String: 
    arr = GetNonEmptyFromColumn("B", 4)  ` Where the function is your code that returns myArr

Comment: @Temptempsson because you cannot convert an array of variants to an array of strings, even if those variants are actually strings. You can easily modify the function itself to return an array of strings.

Comment: @Temptempsson see the added part for transforming it to a function that returns an array of strings.

Comment: @A.S.H Ah I see.. I declared my function as a `String` and not `String()`, thanks for the help

Comment: @A.S.H come give me a hand here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568333/error-getting-oleformat-object-property-of-powerpoint-shape-latebinding-from-e