# Error Getting .OLEFormat.Object property of PowerPoint Shape (LateBinding from Excel-VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, late-binding

I have an Excel VBA tool, that resides inside a PowerPoint Presentaion as an EmbeddedOLEObject.

Process work-flow:

1. A user opens the PowerPoint.
2. Then opens the Excel embedded object in it.
3. Running the code in it updates data in the Excel file, and then exports it to the 1st slide of the PowerPoint it was opened from.

The **problem** starts when the user opens 2 of these PowerPoint presentations. If you open one Presnetation, let's call it "***P1***", then you open a second presentation "***P2***". Then you open the embedded Excel file in "***P2***", the excel gets stuck. When running in debug mode, it goes "crazy" opening numerous VBA windows (without giving an error message), at the following line:

`Set objExcel = myShape.OLEFormat.Object`.

When running this process the other order, If first you open "***P2***", and then "***P1***", open the Embedded Excel file in "***P2***" it works well.

Anyone got a clue ?

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdatePowerPoint()

Dim ppProgram                           As Object
Dim ppPres                              As Object
Dim CurOpenPresentation                 As Object
Dim ppSlide                             As Object
Dim myShape                             As Object
Dim SlideNum                            As Integer
Dim objExcel                            As Object
Dim i                                   As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set ppProgram = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If ppProgram Is Nothing Then
    Set ppProgram = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Else
    If ppProgram.Presentations.Count > 0 Then

        ' loop thorugh all open presentation, then loop through all slides
        ' check each object, check if you find an OLE Embedded object
        For i = 1 To ppProgram.Presentations.Count
            Set CurOpenPresentation = ppProgram.Presentations(i)

            Set ppSlide = CurOpenPresentation.Slides(1) ' only check the first slide for Emb. Excel objects, otherwise not a One-Pager Presentation
                For Each myShape In ppSlide.Shapes
                    Debug.Print myShape.Type & " | " & myShape.Name ' for DEBUG ONLY

                    If myShape.Type = 7 Then ' 7 = msoEmbeddedOLEObject
                        Dim objExcelwbName As String

                        '  ***** ERROR in the Line below *******
                        Set objExcel = myShape.OLEFormat.Object
                        objExcelwbName = objExcel.CustomDocumentProperties.Parent.Name ' get's the workbook name of the Emb. Object

                        If objExcelwbName = ThisWorkbook.Name Then ' compare the name of the workbook the embedded object is in, with ThisWorkbook
                            Set ppPres = CurOpenPresentation
                            GoTo ExitPresFound
                        Else
                            Set objExcel = Nothing ' reset flag
                        End If
                    End If
                Next myShape

NextPresentation:
            Set CurOpenPresentation = Nothing ' clear presentation object
        Next i

    End If ' If ppProgram.Presentations.Count > 0 Then
End If

ExitPresFound:
If ppPres Is Nothing Then ' if One-Pager presentation was not found from all open presentations
    MsgBox "Unable to Locate Presnetation, check if One-Pager Prsentation in Checked-Out (Read-Only Mode)"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Questions: **1**) Steps 1, 2 and 3 are (presumably) manual events that the user initiates?  **2**) This is the code from the embedded Excel? **3**) Is Excel embedded file truly necessary, when a PPT-VBA solution may be more reliable and less prone to this sort of error (NB: I can't reproduce the error).

Comment: @DavidZemens  1) yes. 2) yes. 3) I must have it this way, this file is in a SharePoint site, and out IT won't allow a .pptm or .xlsm files saved. This way, I'm able to save the file as .pptx and still run my Excel code to it.

Comment: Will IT allow a .ZIP file?  :)  SMH at the policies that some companies/managers want to implement...

Comment: @DavidZemens  any idea why I get this error ?

Comment: No, but when I tried to test this I had something happen: I was unable to close Excel except via Task Manager, and got the message like: "Excel is waiting for a response from you". That seems very unrelated to your problem, though.

Comment: Seems like a hard problem. IDK if there is a way to check if the embedded workbook is the same as `ThisWorkbook` without going through `OLEFormat.Object.CustomDocumentProperties.Parent.Name`. It seems that the trouble for Excel is when setting a reference to this `OleFormat.Object` while code is running on the same workbook.

Comment: By the way, why doesn't `myShape.OLEFormat.Object.Name` suffice here?

Comment: Hey, I could not reproduce the buggy scenario either. However, It seems to me that you should not do the test by the name. I prefer, instead of the three problematic lines, this test: `If myShape.OLEFormat.Object Is ThisWorkbook Then`.

Comment: I wonder also, when the workbook's macro is activated, shouldn't the contanining presentation be simply the `ActivePresentation`? Can't we set it this way instead?

Comment: So we can get it by `ppProgram.ActivePresentation`... Tell us if all these alternative methods also fail. All of them worked for me, including yours (without that error).

Comment: @A.S.H first one `If myShape.OLEFormat.Object Is ThisWorkbook Then` raises the same error. the second one is an interesting idea, you mean add in the code on `Workbook_Open` event, `Set ppPres = ActivePresentation` , catch the event while it's always true ?

Comment: Yeah make ppPres a global and set it in Workbook_Open, `Set ppPres = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application").ActivePresentation`. I dont know if it will solve your issue (I hope so), but it looks much simpler and almost guaranteed to work because it will be set as soon as the user clicks the embedded object...

Comment: @A.S.H it should work, just need to test it and you can post as "answer". The only thing I'm worried about, if the user is an inpatient, and while opening the excel from the embedded object, he doesn't wait for the excel to open, and he start to scroll between open PowerPoint presentation, thus switching the ActivePresentation to the "wrong" presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the aim is to capture the presentation that hosts the embedded workbook, and as you confirmed that it looks to you as a good option, the suggested solution is the capture the `ActivePresentation` in the `Workbook_Open` event.

The risk that you raised is legitimate, it is possible  (theoretically, I would say) that the impatient user switches presentations quickly before the workbook loads, but I could not test how likely is this scenario, due to some security alert in my test environment before the wb opens, giving a too large time for that action.

Awaiting your own confirmation :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Tested it a few times today and it worked. I added some extra precautious loops (in case of some "crazy" user)

Comment: @ShaiRado it's a great pleasure to give a little hand to an impressively professional colleague as yours :)

Comment: thanks ;) it's nice to also use this site sometime to get help and creative ideas you don't think of (I really spent so much time over-complicating this one)